# Asignar horas con un random con priodidades

Tags: php, random

Después de buscar en Google y no encontrar nada por el estilo.

Se me ocurrió hacer un array de este estilo

```
$orden= array(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12);
```

y con la función `mt_rand()` generar el numero aleatorio:

```
$longitud = count($orden);    
$hora = mt_rand(0,$longitud);
```

Esto me devolvería la posición de la hora seleccionada.

Pero creo que la solución aportada por @Ricardo D. Quiroga, es más adecuada.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde tengo que asignar unas horas del día aleatoriaménte, pero cada hora tiene una prioridad diferente y un porcentaje de posibilidades de que salga esa hora determinado. La prioridad más alta es 1 y la más baja 5.

Se que la función rand(), te genera un un numero aleatorio, definido por 2 parámetros para determinar entre que rango de números quieres generar el numero aleatorio.

¿Existe alguna función en PHP para indicarles prioridades y el tanto por ciento de posibilidades que salga?

Con la respuesta de @Ricardo D. Quiroga he creado una función y lo he modificado un poco, para que me quede más claro:

```
function horas() {
    // calcular la prioridad
    $rand = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax(); //generar un maldito numero entre 0 y 1
    $prioridad = 0;
    if ($rand < 0.4) { //equivale a 40% probabilidad
        $prioridad = 1;
    } elseif ($rand < 0.7) { // equivale a 30% probabilidad
        $prioridad = 2;
    } elseif ($rand < 0.85) {
        $prioridad = 3;
    } elseif ($rand < 0.95) {
        $prioridad = 4;
    } else { // 5% probabilidad restante
        $prioridad = 5;
    }   

    $tablaHorarioPrioridad = array(
    array("20:00", "21:00", "22:00"), 
        array("17:00", "18:00", "19:00"),
        array("15:00", "16:00"),
        array("12:00", "13:00"),
        array("10:00", "11:00")
    );

    $prioridad1 = $prioridad - 1;
    $longitud = count($tablaHorarioPrioridad[$prioridad1]);     
    $longitud1 = $longitud - 1;

    $posicion = rand(0, $longitud1);        
    $hora = $tablaHorarioPrioridad[$prioridad1][$posicion];

    return $hora;
}
```

Comment: Hola Isaac. Recuerda que este sitio no sustituye a un buscador web. ¿Has investigado e intentado alguna funcion?  ¿Has leido documentaciones para encontrar algo parecido a lo que pides?  Añade tambien ejemplos y las posibles o esperadas salidas aplicando esa funcion de prioridad. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: Cuando edites la pregunta, ¿podrías explicar en qué consiste la prioridad y cómo afectaría el proceso? Porque a simple vista, parece simplemente un código para el porcentaje de posibilidades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola lo primero que veo es un problema de probabilidad, en el gráfico ya que simplemente la suma de todas las probabilidades no puede dar mas de 1, en tu caso, supongo tienes varios agrupamiento según prioridad y basado en la prioridad es indiferente el horario a elegir que coincida con esa prioridad.

en resumen: por ejemplo prioridad 5 con 5% agruparia a (10:00, 11:00)

Por lo que primero deberíamos calcular el grupo en base a la prioridad

```
// calcular la prioridad
$rand = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax(); //generar un número entre 0 y 1
$prioridad = 0;
if ($rand < 0.4) { //equivale a 40% probabilidad
    $prioridad = 1;
} elseif ($rand < 0.7) { // equivale a 30% probabilidad
    $prioridad = 2;
} elseif ($rand < 0.85) {
    $prioridad = 3;
} elseif ($rando < 0.95) {
    $prioridad = 4;
} else { // 5% probabilidad restante
    $prioridad = 5;
}
```

Sabiendo la prioridad solo deberemos elegir un horario entre los que cumplen con tener la misma prioridad, para simplificar la búsqueda los puse dentro de un array bidimensional donde el primer indice define la prioridad.

```
$tablaHorarioPrioridad = array(
    array(20, 21, 22), 
    array(17, 18, 19),
    array(15, 16),
    array(12, 13),
    array(10, 11),
);
```

y bueno el calculo final es elegir un numero de esa lista, todos tienen igual probabilidad por lo que hacemos:

```
$horario = $tablaHorarioPrioridad[$prioridad - 1][rand(0, count($tablaHorarioPrioridad[$prioridad - 1] - 1))];
```

> **Comentarios** Por alguna extraña razón que no termino de entender PHP no posee una función uniforme en los rangos [0, 1) que genere de números pseudo aleatorios, para tener algo similar tuve que recurrir al artilugio `mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()` para tener una aproximación de dicha función la cual es esencial para calculo de cualquier tipo de probabilidad.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor podrías borrar las expresiones "//generar un maldito numero entre 0 y 1" y "No se quien fue el idiota que se le ocurrió". La respuesta es excelente pero tu mismo le restas importancia con esas expresiones.

Comment: Si creo que los quitare pero es que siento eso, cuando revise como generar un numero aleatorio en PHP a leer la documentación, senti una bofetada en la cara, me agarre la cabeza y casi dan ganas de llorar y maldecir (lo que hacia mientras respondía la duda) , no entiendo como se les pudo ocurrir implementar un generador de números pseudo aleatorio `random()` tan malisimo que solo genere enteros y tan limitado, lenguajes ya obsoletos tienen mejores generadores que esta cosa.

Comment: Comprendo y tienes razón en tu planteamiento. Sólo hago esa sugerencia porque me parece que la respuesta está excelente y eso es lo único que la opaca un poco. Un Saludo Ricardo.